# ArrayList does not print removed objects

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner

I have a class called Polynomial with an ArrayList made up of term objects, there is an external file that is read by a Scanner object in my test class. The Scanner reads the line for 4 different key words and acts accordingly. ex. INSERT 3 2. Would call my insert method and print out 3x^2. Now I have a delete method with two parameters. When I call the method in the test class nothing happens, the same thing gets printed and nothing has been removed. Am I missing something or doing it wrong all together? Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
public void delete (int coeff, int expo)
{
  for (int i = 0; i<terms.size(); i++)
  {
      Term current = terms.get(i);
      terms.remove(current.getCoeff());
      terms.remove(current.getExpo());
  }

}
```

I also have a Term class that creates a term object, and has two methods to get the coefficient and exponent.

Here is a snippet of my test class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    // TODO code application logic here
    Polynomial polyList = new Polynomial();



    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File("operations2.txt"));

    while(inFile.hasNext())
    {
       Scanner inLine = new Scanner(inFile.nextLine());

       String insert = inLine.next();

        if(insert.equals("INSERT"))
        {

           int coeff = inLine.nextInt();
           int expo = inLine.nextInt();            
           polyList.insert(coeff, expo);
        }
        if(insert.equals("DELETE"))
        {
            int coeff = inLine.nextInt();
            int expo = inLine.nextInt();
            polyList.delete(coeff, expo);
        }
    }
     System.out.println(polyList.toString());
   }
}
```

Edit: this is a sample of the .txt file that is being read by the scanner class:

```
INSERT 3 2
INSERT 4 4
INSERT 1 6
INSERT 2 0
INSERT 5 2
INSERT 6 3
PRODUCT
DELETE 3 2
INSERT 2 7
DELETE 4 4
INSERT 4 10
```

Edit: Here is the Term class:

```
class Term
{
//instance vars
private int coefficient;
private int exponent;


 public Term(int coeff, int expo)
 {
  coefficient = coeff;
  exponent = expo;

 }
 public int getCoeff()
 {
   return coefficient;
 }
 public int getExpo()
 {
   return exponent;
 }
 @Override
 public int hashCode()
 {
   return  coefficient + exponent;
 }

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object o)
   {

     if (!(o instanceof Term))
     {
       return false;
     }
     Term t = (Term)o;
     return coefficient == t.coefficient && exponent == t.exponent;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `delete()` method is trying to delete the Twrm with the specified coefficients, I recommend the following:

1. Override the `equals()` method to return `true` if the argument is a Term with the same coefficient and exponential
2. Override the `hashCode()` method to return a hash based on the same two values

Since the `equals()` method should make a *value* comparison, such an implementation is quite reasonable.

Once you've done that, your delete method becomes one line:

```
terms.remove(new Term(coeff, expo));
```

---

The implementation should look like this:

```
// in the Term class
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (!(o instanceof Term)
        return false;
    Term t = (Term)o;
    return coeff == t.coeff && expo == t.expo;
}
```

Although overriding the `hashCode` method is not strictly required to make your code work, it is good practice, so here's an example impl:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return 31 * coeff + expo;
}
```

Comment: I actually tried `term.remove(new Term(coeff, expo));` but nothing is removed or replaced in the updated list. Basically I just print the same list twice.

Comment: You must override the equals() method in the Term class. I guarantee it will work.

Comment: `terms.equals(new Term(coeff, expo));` something along these lines?

Comment: @Bohemian In this particular case, because the OP is using a list, an incorrect `hashCode` implementation wouldn't cause it to break, but in general, it is required to make your code work correctly, not just good practice if you're using any hash structure (e.g. map or set)

Comment: @Bohemian I have it working the updated coded is up here, but I noticed its not reading all the `insert.equals("DELETE")` lines. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You're not trying to remove the `Term` from the terms list, but rather trying to remove the coefficient and exponent.

```
  for (int i = 0; i<terms.size(); i++)
  {
      Term current = terms.get(i); // Your list contains Term objects
      terms.remove(current.getCoeff()); // but you are try to removing a coefficient
      terms.remove(current.getExpo()); // and an exponent
  }
```

Just a general note also that removing this way will not work because `i` will be getting larger and your list will be getting smaller. So by the time you get to remove the last term for example (where `i = terms.size() - 1`), there will only be 1 item left in the list. If you're trying to remove all of the items, consider the list's `clear` method.

Comment: Worse, `List.remove(int index)` tries to remove the index-th element of the list.  So, if the second element of the list has coefficient 5, you end up removing the fifth term.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove(int)

Comment: Correct, in this case the results would be not at all what is expected. If `current.getCoeff()` returns an `int` or `current.getExpo()` returns an `int`, I would expect to at the very least see some `IndexOutOfBoundsException`s

Comment: yep you're right I would get `IndexOutOfBoundsException`s. I'm at wit's end here. I feel its something simple and yet I can't get it.

Comment: Also, iif you try to use an iterator you risk a `ConcurrentModificationException`. The only way you can safely remove items from a collection you iterate over is through its `Iterator.remove()` method. However, the loop is unnecessary in any case.

Comment: I also tried what @Bohemian said, but I'm still nowhere. It sounds like `terms.remove(new Term(coeff, expo)` would work, I actually used this in my `insert(int coeff, int expo)` method, instead of `remove()` obviously I used `add()` method. So why doesn't aforementioned `remove()` method work?

Comment: If your `equals` and `hashCode` are properly implemented, then it should work. Can you post your term class and where you initialize and populate the `terms` list? Also edit your post to include the updated `delete` method so we're looking and talking about the same code

Comment: Okay so the `delete` method worked but it seems like it only deleted one coeff and expo from the array. And I have another problem, I would like to have each updated array printed out. Right now if I print out the Array three times it'll just print the final product. ideally I would Like the original array, then the array in reverse, then whatever it deleted or inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Why does your delete method take the arguments coeff and expo ....
...it does not do anything with them.

In fact, the delete method looks very suspicious. You will need to give more detail on what the terms array looks like, right now it makes no sense.

rolfl

Comment: A skeleton class was provided, this is for my programming class, so I cant make any changes to the method declarations.

Comment: Well, that's a strong indication that your implementation of the method *needs* to use the two parameters. Your delete method is wrong...

Comment: I also tried `term.remove(new Term(coeff, expo));` and the result is the same, nothing happens.